# Proper means to configure python build in a Docker container

Tags: python, docker, compiler-errors, long-integer

I am trying to build python from source in a Docker container. The error I'm getting is:

`"This platform's pyconfig.h needs to define PY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG"` (more info below)

My question is : **How does one properly set the `PY_FORMAT_LONG_LONG` in the build configuration ?**. Which environment variable, compiler flags need to be set ? And of course, which is the right part of the fine manual to read ?

These builds were working fine in a a VM, and are now failing various 
base images (CEntOS6/7, Ubuntu 14.04/16.10).

---

Full error at *e.g.* https://ci.sagrid.ac.za/job/python-deploy/39/ARCH=x86_64,GCC_VERSION=4.9.4,NAME=python,OS=centos6,SITE=generic,VERSION=2.7.13/console)

The configuration for the build is at *e.g.* https://github.com/SouthAfricaDigitalScience/python-deploy/blob/master/build-2.7.13.sh

Comment: Can you provide the complete Dockerfile?

Comment: The images are not created with dockerfiles, but with [AnsibleContainer](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container) - https://galaxy.ansible.com/AAROC/CODE-RADE-container/
The images can be obtained from [quay.io](https://quay.io/organization/aaroc) - _e.g._ `docker pull quay.io/aaroc/code-rade-build-containers-build-slave:ubuntu1610`

Comment: Looks like this one has some info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764692/how-do-i-get-python-to-compile-with-libz